# Is there a way to compare different variables with json?

Tags: json, ansible

I'm trying to compare running services pre/post reboot on linux servers. But I'm unable to get it to output the differences.

The function I've got currently outputs the pre/post state to disk. But I would prefer to get the output registered directly as a variable

```
- name: populate service facts
  service_facts:
  register: facts

- name: Outputting running services
  debug: var=item
  with_items: "{{ facts|json_query(query)}}"
  vars:
    query: 'ansible_facts.services.* | [?state == `running`].name'
```

Should end up in a function looking something similar to

```
    - name: Missing running services
      debug:
         msg: {{ item }}
      with_items:
        - {{ facts_pre }}
        - {{ facts_post }}
      vars:
        query: 'ansible_facts.services.* | [?state == `running`].name'
      when: facts_pre.ansible_facts.services != facts_post.ansible_facts.services
```

The result should be something similar as if the following state is shown pre-reboot

```
ok: [hostname] => (item=NetworkManager.service) => {
    "item": "NetworkManager.service"
}
ok: [hostname] => (item=systemd-udevd.service) => {
    "item": "systemd-udevd.service"
}
ok: [hostname] => (item=sshd.service) => {
    "item": "sshd.service"
}
ok: [hostname] => (item=systemd-journald.service) => {
    "item": "systemd-journald.service"
}
```

and the journald fails during boot for some reason

```
ok: [hostname] => (item=NetworkManager.service) => {
    "item": "NetworkManager.service"
}
ok: [hostname] => (item=systemd-udevd.service) => {
    "item": "systemd-udevd.service"
}
ok: [hostname] => (item=sshd.service) => {
    "item": "sshd.service"
}
```

It would register systemd-journald.service to it's own variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query gives the list of running services

```
- service_facts:
- set_fact:
    running_services_A: "{{ ansible_facts.services|dict2items|
                            json_query('[?value.state == `running`].key') }}"
```

*"To compare running services"* use [difference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) filter. For example

```
- debug:
    msg: "Services running at A but not at B
          {{ running_services_A|difference(running_services_B) }}"
```

(not tested)

---

Notes

- It's not necessary to register the output of *`service_facts`*. Variable *`ansible_facts.services`* is automatically created. See [service_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html#service-facts-return-service-state-information-as-fact-data).

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use a `with_items` clause that you have the `intersection` of the lists before and after reboot. and it will display all the differences between the 2 lists.

Sample playbook with a `sleep` task to give you enough time to stop/start a service from another session, so that you can capture it in the `facts_post` variable:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    web_folder:

  tasks:
  - name: populate service facts BEFORE
    service_facts:
    register: facts_pre

  - name: sleep to stop/start a service
    shell: sleep 10

  - name: populate service facts AFTER
    service_facts:
    register: facts_post

  - name: Missing running services
    debug:
       var: item
    with_items:
    - "{{ facts_pre | json_query(query) | symmetric_difference(facts_post | json_query(query)) }}"
    vars:
      query: 'ansible_facts.services.* | [?state == `running`].name'
```

hope it helps.